# How can I alter a third-party theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I found a theme that I really like, but I want to change one aspect of it – the color of the text in html/php/asp/etc. pages. Specifically, I'd like to change the text color in the source code so it's easily distinguishable from the code itself.
Is this possible without re-writing the whole theme?

I tried doing this in the user settings:

```
"workbench.colorTheme": "Colorful Dark" {
text.color: #ffffff;
}
```

But, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

See if there is a documentation available about that theme. If not then find these lines on that theme

```
`textBlockQuote.background:` Background color for block quotes in text.

`textBlockQuote.border:` Border color for block quotes in text.

`textCodeBlock.background:` Background color for code blocks in text.

`textLink.activeForeground:` Foreground color for active links in text.

`textLink.foreground:` Foreground color for links in text.

`textPreformat.foreground:` Foreground color for preformatted text segments.

`textSeparator.foreground:` Color for text separators.
```

and change their value as you need. For more about VS Theme Color visit this Microsoft Visual Studio Color Reference Documentation.    https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference

Comment: There's no documentation on the theme. I think the author dropped off the planet.

Comment: However, I've been to the page you cited already. It appears to refer to the _theme itself_, instead of the code colors in the theme, which is what I'm after:
https://ibb.co/b09N47

Comment: Right. I've been able to discover how to change the comments within the editor:
`
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Colorful Dark]": {
            "comments": "#818181"
            
        }
    },
`

Just not the text in the editor (the text that shows on the html page.)